# Angular js get val() from ng-modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this code in my project

```
var $reason = this.$el.find('select.reason');
```

if i will do this
    $reason.val();

I will get this output:

```
0:select.form-control.reason
context:undefined
length:1
selector:"select.reason"
```

How i can achieve this in angular js using modal value? or something else

Comment: Do you want to get the value present in html element or you want the entire html element?

Comment: entire html element, value i can get by doing $scope.modal

Answer (score 1):

For having the HTML element just access the [0]. You can simply use:

```
console.log($reason[0]);
```